# Vue v-for retrieve index of current item

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm looping through some items and I'm facing a bit of a problem.
I'd like to receive the index of the current item in the items array.

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
<td> currently viewing the {{ *index of item in items array* }}th item</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `v-for="(item, ndx) in items"`. Then use ndx. Or whatever you want to call it. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for

Comment: @BerendBaardse Welcome to SO! Please write your own answer and accept it, instead of including the solution in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Using `v-for="(item, ndx) in items"` Then using ndx as the index of the current item.